# Windows: Delete file with invalid character "

Tags: windows

I have a file on a `Z:\` network mapped drive.

It is in a folder `M` and the file is named `13" vs 15" vs 17".png`

I cannot delete the file or folder in Windows explorer, getting the error:

```
The file name you specified is not valid or too long
```

I have also tried command prompt `Z:\>del /P M` I get the error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I have also seen some other suggestions on here using something like `Z:\>del "\\?\Z:\M\13" vs 15" vs 17".png"` and I am either typing command incorrectly or getting error:

```
Could Not Find \\?Z\Z:\M\13
Could Not Find Z:\vs
```

I am not too sure how to escape the " and spaces in the filename in command prompt.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to rename the file.

Comment: cannot rename it

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I have two PCs: Windows 10 and Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

That's how I clear a folder in such a case if conventional methods do not work:

1. create an empty folder somewhere, where you have access
2. start CMD as admin
3. Execute: `robocopy 'Z:\empty-folder' 'Z:\M\' /purge /w:2 /r:1 /LOG:'Z:\Log_purge.txt'`

This basically syncs to the empty folder and gets rid of everything which was not present in the source folder. Since its empty, it gets rid of everything.

See [robocopy copy-options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#copy-options) for further information on this command.

Comment: Even robocopy can't delete it
ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Deleting Extra File Z:\M\13" vs 15" vs 17".png
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.